# How can i calculate elongation of a convex hull in opencv?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, convex-hull, feature-extraction

I have found this way to calculate elongation basing on image moments

```
#ELONGATION
def elongation(m):
    x = m['mu20'] + m['mu02']
    y = 4 * m['mu11']**2 + (m['mu20'] - m['mu02'])**2
    return (x + y**0.5) / (x - y**0.5)

mom = cv2.moments(unicocnt, 1)    
elongation = elongation(mom)
```

How can i calculate elongation of a Convex Hull?

```
hull = cv2.convexHull(unicocnt)
```

where 'unicocnt' is a contour that was taken with find contours.

Comment: Can't you run the same function over the contour of the hull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, convexHull output a vector of indices of points. You have to set the returnPoints argument to 1 to output a vector of points that you can then pass to cv2.moments.

Comment: there is only hull and clockwise argument

Comment: Which version of OpenCV do you use ? [Here is](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=rect#convexhull) the doc for cv2.convexHull and I can see 4 arguments.